# Find an isomorphism between $\mathbb H^1 \approx \mathbb C \times \mathbb R $ and a subgroup of $GL_3 (\mathbb R)$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

The group operation of $\mathbb H$ is defined by:
$$[x,y,t]\cdot [x',y',t']= [x+x',y+y',t+t'-2xy'+2x'y] $$
The subgroup of $GL_3 (\mathbb R)$ has the form 
$$G= \Bigg\{\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & a & c \\
0 & 1 & b \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}: a,b,c \in \mathbb R \Bigg\}$$

My guess is since
$$ [x,y,t][x',y',t']=[x+x',y+y',t+t'+(x+y)(x'-y')-(x-y)(x'+y')]$$

Define the function \begin{align*}
\phi: & \mathbb H^1 \rightarrow G \\
&       [x,y,t] \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & x+y & f(x,y,t) \\
0 & 1 & x-y \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

So $\phi([x,y,t]\cdot[x',y',t'])=\phi([x,y,t])\cdot\phi([x',y',t'])$. But I couldn't figure out $f$, can someone give a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this going to work?  $H^1$ appears to be abelian, but $G$ is not.

Comment: @D_S $H$ is not abelian.